# Copy data from one worksheet to other based on condition

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy data from one worksheet to another blank worksheet in a workbook. It has three columns where in I want to search a specific 'Unit' value and just copy all of the records with similar 'Unit' values into second worksheet with similar column structure.

```
**Doc_number**      **Doc_version**           **Unit**  
43449                     01                      D013-LAG R  
43450                     02                      D013-LAG R  
43451                     01                      D013-DAMP  
43452                     02                      D013-DAMP
```

Output should be like this if I provide D013-LAG R as input value ;

```
**Doc_number**      **Doc_version**            **Unit**  
43449                  01                     D013-LAG R  
43450                  02                     D013-LAG R
```

I want to paste the selected column to the DELIVERY sheet like if I pass 'Unit' value as 'D03-LAG R' then the output in the DELIVERY file should be just like as follows;

```
Doc_version      Unit
01              D013-LAG R
02              D013-LAG R
```

It's more like I want to select entire row and then paste the data to another worksheet to the columns I want to. I don't want entire row to be pasted as it is.

I don't have much experience in VBA and have already tried doing the code which results in copying of the last record encountered in the loop. Need your advice.

```
Sub Row_Copy()
Dim sheet1 As Worksheet, sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, k As Integer
Dim Sheet1LR As Long, Sheet2LR As Long

Set sheet1 = Sheets("MASTER")
Set sheet2 = Sheets("DELIVERY")

Sheet1LR = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Sheet2LR = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

i = 2
k = Sheet2LR

Do Until i = Sheet1LR
If Trim(sheet1.Cells(i, 26).Value) = "D013-LAG R" Then
    With sheet1
        .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 26)).Copy
    End With

    With sheet2
        .Cells(k, 1).PasteSpecial
        .Cells(k, 1).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    End With
    End If
    k = k + 1
    i = i + 1

Loop

MsgBox (Complete)
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

This is the latest code I am using;

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim LSearchRow As Long
Dim LCopyToRow As Long
Dim CopyFromSht As Worksheet
Dim CopyToSht As Worksheet
Dim LCnt As Long


On Error GoTo Err_Execute
Set CopyFromSht = Workbooks("TestRow.xlsm").Sheets("MASTER")
Set CopyToSht = Workbooks("TestRow.xlsm").Sheets("DELIVERY")

With CopyFromSht
    'Start search in row 4
    LSearchRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
    LCopyToRow = 2

    For LCnt = 2 To LSearchRow

    'If value in column Z = "Unit as needed", copy entire row to Sheet2
        If .Range("Z" & LCnt).Value = "D013-LAG R" Then

        'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
            .Rows(LCnt).Copy Destination:=CopyToSht.Rows(LCopyToRow)

        'Move counter to next row
            LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

        End If
   Next LCnt
End With
```

Comment: Write the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome Monty to Stack Overflow. Please look at how to ask - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. "search and research". There is lots of code snippets on copy data in Excel which you can learn from. For example, to combine data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823009/excel-copy-data-from-multiple-worksheets and on finding data e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252879/excel-vba-update-find-data-loop-through-multiple-worksheets-copy-range

Comment: Hi @besciualex Added the code I am playing with. But from this I am not able to extract the required data to Delivery worksheet

Comment: Why don't you just use manual filters?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I have simplified the sheet for example purpose.. I am not able to get the logic which I shall use in the larger sheet with huge data. That's why I cannot use the manual filter.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a macro that might give you an idea how to resolve your problem:

```
Sub CopyRows()

  ' Variables
  Dim row_src As Integer
  Dim row_dest As Integer

  ' Inizialize row within destination sheet
  row_dest = 1

  ' Loop over all rows in source sheet
  For row_src = 1 To 32767

    ' Go to correct cell within source sheet
    Sheets("Source").Select
    Range("B" & CStr(row_src)).Select

    ' Done if this row is empty
    If (ActiveCell.Value = "") Then
      Exit For
    End If

    ' Copy row if it's the header or if match found
    If (row_src = 1) Or (ActiveCell.Value = "D013-LAG R") Then

      ' Copy source row
      Rows(CStr(row_src) & ":" & CStr(row_src)).Select
      Selection.Copy

      ' Go to destination row
      Sheets("Destination").Select
      Rows(CStr(row_dest) & ":" & CStr(row_dest)).Select

      ' Copy row
      ActiveSheet.Paste

      ' Make sure next row is copied on the right place
      row_dest = row_dest + 1

    End If

  Next

End Sub
```

In case you want to copy only a few columns from the source to the destination sheet, try this:

```
' Copy columns B to E of source row
Range("B" & CStr(row_src) & ":E" & CStr(row_src)).Select
Selection.Copy

' Go to destination
Sheets("Destination").Select
Range("B" & CStr(row_dest)).Select

' Copy these columns
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

In case the columns to be copied are not consecutive (for instance B, D and F):

```
Range("B" & CStr(row_src) & ",D" & CStr(row_src) & ",F" & CStr(row_src)).Select
Range("F" & CStr(row_src)).Activate
Selection.Copy
```

By the way, I don't know this all by heart.

You can easily find out the details by executing within Excel:

- Menu View/Macro/Register Macro (or something similar; I got the Italian version)

- Do manually anything you want to automate

- Menu View/Macro/Interrput registration

- Menu View/Macro/View/Modify

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks @Robert Kock for the code but it doesn't work.. I tried to change it according to my use but still I am stuck. I just want to pass a value to the code which it will search in MASTER worksheet and will copy the data to DELIVERY sheet based on the matched search term

Comment: Could you please explain what goes wrong? Does it give you an error or does is simply not work? Could you provide your code as well?

Comment: I have provided the code I am using. It is working but can you guide me  how to copy and paste selective columns based on the 'Unit' value provided.

Comment: Do you mean that which columns should be copied depends on the value you're searching for? Could you provide an example please?

Comment: I have updated the question. I want to copy entire row but copy only the selected columns to the DELIVERY sheet where the Column header matches with that of MASTER data sheet. Hope it clarifies.